# Titanium Studio Error on iOS app - undefined is not an object

Tags: ios, ipad, titanium

Getting an error in Titanium and seem to figure it out. Here is the error:

Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.source.center.x')

Here is the function where the error is occurring:

```
function MoveStart(e) {
    switch(win.orientation)
    {
        // LANDSCAPE_RIGHT
        default:
        e.source.ox = e.globalPoint.y - e.source.center.x;
            e.source.oy = win.height - e.globalPoint.x - e.source.center.y;
        //alert('x: ' + e.source.ox + ' y: '+ e.source.oy);
        break;
    }
                       }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you have any problem to understand the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message clearly indicates that the `center` property is undefined for `e.source`

Use **post-layout** event instead  `center.x` to achieve your goal.